# Can't install JPype on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, 64-bit, neo4j, ubuntu-12.04, jpype

I've consulted this:
[Cannot install JPype on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949160/cannot-install-jpype-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

And I'm following the tutorial here:
https://github.com/johanlundberg/neo4j-django-tutorial

It seems I'm still having a problem installing JPype, despite having done both the things in that answer:

`sudo apt-get install python-jpype`

and

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

The error I'm getting, when I run

`python neo4jtut/manage.py syncdb`

tells me the module doesn't exist, with

`home/username/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/_backend.py", line 83, in <module>
    import jpype, os
ImportError: No module named jpype`

Can anyone tell what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try installing it like in the tutorial? Eg, without a virtualenv, `sudo pip install /path/to/JPype-0.5.4.2.zip`?

Aside- have you considered [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django)?

Comment: I didn't change anything, but it suddenly worked when I ran it again a few days later.  Neo4django looks pretty fantastic, thanks, Matt!